# Digitizing from physical soil map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I need a shape (or raster) soil map of Burundi. I have a .jpg physical soil map of the region in high quality, which I have imported into ArcMAP and georeferenced to the correct projection.
In stead of creating hundreds of polygons myself by clicking, isn't there a possibility to classify the .jpg image based on its RGB values? Or is there a possibility to select regions of similar colour (in the jpg) and make a polygon out of it?

Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution to help automate the digitisation is to use the [Arcscan](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_ArcScan/000w00000001000000/) tool-bar. It allows you clean up your raster image and to turn it into a two colour image. You then use the vectorization tools to effectively trace the border of your feature and create a polygon. There are Interactive and Automatic options which you can use depending on how many polygons you need to generate.

[image: Interactive digitisation]

This tutorial from ESRI gives a good step by step guide and was a useful starting point for me:
[ArcScan Tutorial](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/arcscan-tutorial.pdf)

Comment: Thank you! that seems to be what I am looking for. Now getting it to work...